# React native textInput only numbers tablet

Tags: javascript, react-native, numbers, textinput, input-field

[image]

I would need that when I click on the input field, only the numeric keyboard comes out.

On smartphones. it works, but trying on the tablet the numeric keyboard comes out as default but gives the user the possibility to be able to change with the letters.

Is there a way to make user unable to change.

```js
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput placeholder="useless placeholder" keyboardType="numeric" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 46,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the keyboard type [here](https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/)

Have u tried keyboardType="number-pad"?

Comment: Already tried it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that `phone-pad` is the solution.